# Template to provide static HTML wrapping a page-specific value

Tags: kentico

I am creating a page template. Each page using the template will have a single unique value that gets embedded into the page HTML. The rest of the HTML is constant for all pages. Assume the following is the desired result:

```
<a href="www.example.com/id">click me</a>
```

I want a template that provides `<a href="www.example.com/` and `">click me</a>`, while allowing the individual pages (content admins) to provide `id`.

I've tried using an Editable Text web part, and putting the "before" and "after" HTML in the HTML Envelope before and after sections, and adding the ID on the "Page" tab. However, that is not quite working. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done.  What you'd want to do is add that field to the page type fields you're adding those pages with.  For instance, say you have a list of locations under `/locations`.

i.e.:
`/location/chicago`
`/location/new-york`
`/location/minneapolis`

The locations themselves (Chicago, New York, Minneapolis) are your custom page type and have a unique field called `LocationID`.  On your template, add a static text webpart (not static HTML because the WYSIWYG editor overwrites the markup you add) and simply add this:

`<a href="http://www.example.com/{%LocationID%}">click me</a>`

If the `LocationID` field has a exists AND has a value, it will output it, otherwise it will just leave the URL `http://www.example.com/`

If you didn't want to show that link at all on other pages, then set the Show for page types property based on the page type you want it to show for in the Visibility section of the static text webpart.

Comment: I was using the out-of-the-box page type of "Page (menu item)", since the pages are very simple. I had considered trying something with a custom page type, but was hoping to avoid if possible, just to keep the complexity to a minimum. I guess it's worth it if it actually works. Do you have any ideas that don't involve a custom page type? I'll try what you said in the mean time. Thanks.

Comment: Then add that field to the regular Page page type.  Just know for every page that is added, it will be there.  No need to complicate things if you don't need to.

Comment: Thank you Brenden. I went with creating a new page type as you laid out in you answer. It works just as I wanted, and isn't too much overhead. The web part names are confusing to me--I wouldn't have thought "Static Text" would be the one I needed to create dynamic HTML :)